# ODP.NET Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, database-connection, .net-4.8

I do realise this or anything similar has been asked here before, but I did my research and on the third day I have had enough. Please do keep in my I am fairly new to all of this.

**OVERVIEW**

I am coding a testing app which purpose is to try and test an ODP.NET connection to our database on a test server.
Now there are two main ways to do so. First is a regular TCP connection which works just fine. The issue comes when I attempt to use an SSL one.
Everything important is written in tnsnames.ora file which is placed in oracle12/.../NETWORK/ADMIN on the machine from which the code is compiled. We are using a wallet "system" which is properly stored and linked where it should be linked (hence one way of connecting works).
The test server is on a different machine.

**ERROR**

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: Oracle Communication: Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string

inner exception: NetworkException: ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file

**CODE**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;

namespace testODP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            OracleConnection conn;

            connectionString = @"User Id = :) ; Password = (: ;DATA SOURCE=sb-dtb-test.vsskb.cz:2486/SB04S;PERSIST SECURITY INFO = True";

            //connectionString = @"User Id = :) ; Password = (: ; DATA SOURCE=sb-dtb-test.vsskb.cz:1523/SB04; PERSIST SECURITY INFO = True";

            conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

The commented connection string works just fine and has no issues whatsoever. However it is the first one which is the chief source of my woes and a renderer of the previously mentioned errors.

**DEPENDENCIES, PROJECT SETTINGS AND REFERENCES**

C# WinFormApp .NET 4.8

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (21.11.0)

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework (21.9.0)

System.Data.SqlClient (4.8.5)

Visual Studio 2019 (x86)

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 (x86)

**NOTES**

At first I have tried all possible connection string combinations to no avail. Then I was instructed by other Stack Overflow issue to check if all the settings and versions given it is a secured connection are properly set up. Which they do appear to be.

**QUESTION**

Why is one way working and the other, more important, not?

What should I try to fix the issue and get rid of those pesky errors?